# C# How set a non-numeric value to 0

Tags: c#, default-value, zero

I have to write a code that will ask for 3 integers values and find the greatest one. However, if the user enters a non numeric value this must have the value of zero. So far i wrote this

```
        int a, b, c;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter value 1:");
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter value 2:");
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter value 3:");
        c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (a > b && a > c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The greatest value is: {0}", a);
        }
        if (b > a && b > c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The greatest value is: {0}", b);
        }
        if (c > a && c > b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The greatest value is: {0}", c);
        }
```

This code works only with numbers.
My problem is that i can't make a non numeric input have the value of zero.
I tried using string instead of int, so there is no error but i can not make use ">" with strings in the if statements and i also tried using as default, because when is default so it is zero.

Thank you

Comment: Use [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just replace:

```
x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

With...

```
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int x);
```

If the input can't be parsed, `x` will end up being 0.

Comment: it workds. but i had to remove the int
like this
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out  x);

thank you very much

Comment: That's a good fix. I had overlooked the fact that you had already declared a, b, and c.

Comment: That's because you previously declared it, but as pointed out in the answer that's not strictly necessary as it can be declared inline with the try parse call.  This was introduced in C# 7 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a function that does the try catch, in this way you print a message saying that the input was not a number.

```
static int Check(string input)
        {
            int result;
            try
            {
                result = Convert.ToInt32(input);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input not integer, the value assigned is 0");
                result = 0;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

For implementing you just call:

```
a = Check(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: `tryParse` avoids the try/catch. Try/Catch is expensive. Although a micro-optimization here, it's a good habit to prefer TryXXX over Try/Catch and Convert.

Comment: Some good reading on the subject https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: thank you for your answer. i didnt learn yet this try/catch but i will give a look on it. =D